# Android Q emulator - Build.VERSION.SDK_INT returns 28

Tags: android, sdk, target-sdk, targetsdkversion, android-10.0

```
 Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

returns 28 instead of 29 when running on Android Q emulator.  Is there anything I am missing?  I am trying to add logic specifically for Android Q but I do not know how to determine this version correctly.

app.gradle file contains

```
    targetSdkVersion = 'Q'
    compileSdkVersion = 'android-Q'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before the API is finalized and officially becomes API 29 (where you'd use `compileSdkVersion 29`, etc), you must use [`BuildCompat.isAtLeastQ()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/os/BuildCompat#isAtLeastQ()):

> Checks if the device is running on a pre-release version of Android Q or newer.
>
> Note: This method will return false on devices running release versions of Android. When Android Q is finalized for release, this method will be deprecated and all calls should be replaced with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that Ian's solution requires AndroidX and is only available from Java/Kotlin code.

If your project is not ready for AndroidX just yet, or you need the value in a resource or the manifest, you can use `bool` resources:

- Create `res/values/bools.xml` and put `<bool name="isQ">false</bool>` in there
- Create `res/values-v29/bools.xml` and put `<bool name="isQ">true</bool>` in there

At this point, if you refer to the `isQ` resource, you will get `true` on Android Q and higher devices, `false` otherwise.